# problem with query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in my database first `saveimage` which contains id and url of each image second `score` which contains id and score of each image this scores are not unique - each row in score table is user rating to a image so one image may has several rows in score.

Now I want find images with highest score in database

I tried

```
select * from saveimage 
where saveimage.id in (select top 100 id,SUM(avgscore) 
                       from score 
                       group by id  
                       order by SUM(avgscore) desc)
```

Which is not working because

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list

So what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT TOP 100 img.id,
       img.url,
       SUM(sc.avgscore) as totalScore
FROM saveimage img
INNER JOIN score sc
ON img.id = sc.id
GROUP BY img.id, img.url
ORDER BY SUM(sc.avgscore) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 columns in your subquery (you have id and sum(avgscore)).

If you are trying to find the top 100 scores for each image, try something like this:

```
select * 
from saveimage 
where saveimage.id in 
  (select top 100 id 
   from score 
   group by id  
   order by SUM(avgscore) desc)
```